# Express in NodeJS: URL param breaks routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use express to serve my index.html, its dependancies as well as handle url params. For some reason, adding a URL param seems to break the pathing.

- My basic nodeJS webapp has the following folder structure:

```
|- server.js (nodeJS server code)
|- public (dir)
     | - app.js (app logic dependancy)
     | - index.html (base HTML file to be served from server.js)
```

- `index.html` is importing `app.js` as follows:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>`

- My express routes are as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
 
app.get('/:country', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html', {country:req.params.country});
}
```

I want the app to be served even when the country param is used.
However, when I add the URL param route, the above route stops working because express looks for index.html in the folder root, resulting in a 404.
Eg: http://localhost:3000/usa

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/john/Projects/TestApp/index.html'
```

Comment: Both app.js and index.html are already in your express static directory. Why do you need to serve app.js on its own route? You should, from index.html, be able to reference app.js (ie: <script src="{{host?}}/public/app.js">

Comment: @Node_Ninja I removed the app.js route as you suggested, let me update the question.

Comment: I have removed `app.js` route as index.html can find it by default - unless a URL param is used. This is what I want to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I add the URL param route, the above route stops working because express looks for index.html in the folder root, resulting in a 404. Eg: http://localhost:3000/usa
>
> `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/john/Projects/TestApp/index.html'`

You should add `public` to the directory path, then.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Or, to work cross-platform:

```
const path = require("path")
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"))
})
```

Comment: Sorry Cadence, this did not work, and in fact, broke the app.js route too. As I mentioned in the question, in my current code the app.js route breaks only when I introduce the URL param route.

Comment: you updated answer prints `app.js` on my browser console as a string. No errors, but `app.js` is not imported into the HTML